# AMS-Simons travel grant

Tags: mathematics, funding

My question is regarding the [American Mathematical Society-Simons travel grant](http://www.ams.org/programs/travel-grants/AMS-SimonsTG#eligibility) and I wanted to know what makes one competitive for AMS-Simons travel grant.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "competitive"? Like, what qualities/quantities make you "win" a funding from Simons?

Comment: Yes. That is what exactly I meant by competitive.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I'm not sure this is answerable, but let's see, maybe it is.

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this beyond the obvious: make sure your rec letter is going to be good, do good research, write a reasonable research summary.  (I'm also not convinced there is any good answer beyond this...)  I just wanted to note that you shouldn't be dissuaded from applying if you have some departmental funding.  I get in the high three digits  of "professional development funds" from my uni every year, but it didn't disqualify me from the AMS-Simons (which is 2k/yr).

Comment: @Mark I think what you wrote *is* a very good answer. While obvious to you, it might not be obvious to the OP.

Comment: @Mark Can you please turn your comment into an answer so that I can vote it up?